# Converting a 24-hour time String to DateTime using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table with a 'timefrom' column and a 'timeto' column that stores times in 24-hour format ("09:30", "23:15", etc).

How do I select rows where the current date (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP I would think) is between 'timefrom' and 'timeto'?

**edit**: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2008+

```
WHERE
    CONVERT(time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        BETWEEN
             CONVERT (time, timefrom + ':00', 108)
             AND
             CONVERT (time, timeto + ':00', 108)
```

You could of course fix your design to avoid conversion by using a `time` column

Comment: Assuming I have 'timefrom' and 'timeto' stored as times, won't I still have to use CONVERT to get the time value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: @user982119: correct. But it matters if you want indexes on timefrom and timeto. The CONVERT on these will mean any index won't be used

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
DECLARE @24Hour TIME
SET @24Hour = '17:13'
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @24Hour, 100) AS '12Hour'
```